# How to hit the weak point on a vehicle?

Tags: vehicles, cyberpunk-red

In the Vehicle Combat section of Cyberpunk RED, under “Structural Damage Points,” it says:

> Shooting a vehicle with a ranged weapon still requires you to hit your shot using the range table.

However, in the next section, “Aiming for Vehicle Weak Points,” it says:

> . . . if the vehicle is moving, you must beat a DV13 to hit its weak point and the -8 penalty still applies.

So how does one go about hitting the weak point on a moving vehicle?

Do they:

- Just roll an attack at DV13? Afaik this isn’t how ranged attacks work for regular combatants; those have to use the range table, as do regular ranged attacks on a vehicle. Also, bypassing the range table means it’s easier to hit a weak point at long range e.g. with a pistol than it is regularly.
- Roll the ranged attack to hit with the range table, *then* roll the DV13 to hit the weak point? (Or vice versa?) This feels too clunky to be right, and afaict this isn’t how ranged weak point attacks work vs a normal opponent.

What am I missing? How does a player go about hitting the weak point on a moving vehicle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The DV13 roll is to hit a moving vehicle with a melee weapon

The second passage you quote is the continuation of a sentence about making melee attacks against vehicles, and should be read as only applying to those attacks. The issue is that vehicles can't dodge attacks, and since melee attacks are only opposed by dodges there's no DV table for them. For non-moving vehicles you hit with melee weapons automatically. That is too strong against moving vehicles though, so they give you a (relatively low) DV to roll against instead.

I think the intent can be spelled out most clearly with a small table:

|  | Regular Attack | Aimed Shot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Non-moving vehicle** | Automatic hit (but why not aim?) | Automatic hit on a weak point |
| **Moving vehicle** | Melee vs DV13 | Melee - 8 vs DV13 (effectively DV21) |

Comment: 100% that’s what it was, thanks so much! They put the word Melee in the sweet spot where I skipped right over it.